# ImportError: cannot import name 'passUser' from 'userUpdate.models'

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Hello everyone I am trying to build a website with django that gets info from the form and makes api calls using those parameters.
I am very newby on django and I build a model for this but i cannot import this model it says

```
-------->>>>>>python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 110, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\anaconda3\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\SystemConsole\userUpdate\models.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\SystemConsole\userUpdate\views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from userUpdate.forms import userPassResetForm
  File "C:\Users\berat.berkol\SystemConsole\userUpdate\forms.py", line 2, in <module>
    from userUpdate.models import passUser
ImportError: cannot import name 'passUser' from 'userUpdate.models' (C:\Users\berat.berkol\SystemConsole\userUpdate\models.py)
```

on Windows cmd. I tried this without making a model but if I don't use models i can't render the form to the template.

Here is my home.html

```html
<div class="u-form u-form-1">
    <form action="{% url 'userPassreset' %}" method="post" class="u-clearfix u-form-spacing-15 u-form-vertical u-inner-form" style="padding: 15px;" source="custom" name="send">
    {% csrf_token %}
        <div class="u-form-group u-form-name u-form-group-1">
            {{form.as_p}}
            {{form.username}}
        </div> 
        <div class="u-align-right u-form-group u-form-submit u-form-group-6">
            <input type="submit" value="Sadece Mesaj Gönder" class="u-active-white u-border-0 u-border-radius-10 u-btn u-btn-round u-btn-submit u-button-style u-palette-2-base u-btn-1" name="sendmessage">
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

urls.py (App)

```py
from django.urls import path, re_path
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from . import views
app_name='userUpdate'
   urlpatterns = [
       path('', views.userUpdate, name='home'),
       path('login/', 
            LoginView.as_view(
                template_name='login.html'), 
                name="login"),
       path('userPassreset',views.passResetView.as_view(),name='userPassreset'),]
```

urls.py (Project)

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib.auth.views import LoginView
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView   
app_name='userUpdate'
   urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('login/',include('django.contrib.auth.urls')),
        path('', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='home.html'), name='home'),]
```

models.py

```py
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from . import views
class passUser(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=100)
    password = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=100)
    number = models.CharField(blank=False,max_length=100)
    message = models.CharField(blank=True,max_length=300)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "passUser"
```

forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from userUpdate.models import passUser
class userPassResetForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = passUser
        fields = "__all__"
```

views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from datetime import timedelta
from django.utils import timezone
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_protect
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator
from django.urls import reverse
import requests
from userUpdate.forms import userPassResetForm
from django.views import View
@csrf_protect
class passResetView(View):

    def get(self,request):

        form=userPassResetForm()
        return render('home.html')

    def post(self,request):
        passResetuser=self.model.objects.get(pk=2)
        form=userPassResetForm(request.POST,instance=passResetuser)

        if form.is_valid():
            username=form.cleaned_data('username')
            password=form.cleaned_data('password')
            number=form.cleaned_data('number')
            message=form.cleaned_data('message')

        context={'form':form}
        return render(request,'home.html',context)
```

settings.py

```
import os
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.contrib.messages import constants as message_constants

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
reverse_lazy("accounts:list")
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('registration/login')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse_lazy('home')



# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

DEBUG = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
     'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'userUpdate.apps.UserupdateConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',

]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'SystemConsole.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        "DIRS": [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'SystemConsole.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = '/home/SystemConsole/static'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]

SITE_ID = 1
```

apps.py

```
from django.apps import AppConfig
class UserupdateConfig(AppConfig):
      name = 'userUpdate'
```

Thank you for your help for now.

And Here is the directory tree :

[image]

Comment: could you provide all the error message please? Do you know in which module the import error comes from?

Comment: I added the full error code and the imports now @blondelg

Comment: Thanks, can you please provide the directory structure of your project ?

Comment: I provided that too. @blondelg

Comment: The path to **userUpdate** seems wrong, it is at the root of your project and your server tries to find it within **SystemConsole** folder ```C:\Users\berat.berkol\SystemConsole\userUpdate\models.py```. How do you declare your apps and roots in the **settings.py** file?

Comment: I added settings.py too how can i change this or should i move the userUpdate inside the SystemConsole folder ?

Comment: you can try to replace 'userUpdate.apps.UserupdateConfig' by 'userUpdate' in installed app list, please provide also userUpdate.apps.py

Comment: I replace it as you said but nothing changed @blondelg

Comment: please provide also userUpdate/apps.py

Comment: I already provided that @blondelg

Comment: What is the name of the directory containing **manage.py** ?

Comment: "SystemConsole" same as the project name

Comment: Is there a reason to call views in models module? If not, try to drop **from . import views**

Comment: I dropped that import and it worked thank you but now i have another problem :) I cant render the form on the template. There is only button with "Sadece Mesaj Gönder" value and when i click the button i see "Method Not Allowed (POST): /
Method Not Allowed: /" error on the console @blondelg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved by dropping "from . import views" from models. Thanks to @blondelg in comments